# Prove that a group is a quaternion group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The representation of the Quaternion group is
$$\mathrm{Q} = \langle -1,i,j,k \mid (-1)^2 = 1, \;i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1 \rangle.$$

Does this imply that as long as I have found a group with $4$ generators, with one element "$-1$" that has order 2 and 3 elements $i,j,k$ that satisfy the equation $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$, I have proved that the group is the Quaternion group?

Comment: What is **your** definition of "a quaternion group" ... ??

Comment: Hi @DonAntonio, I define $\mathrm{Q}$ as so ($\mathrm{Q} = \langle -1,i,j,k \mid (-1)^2 = 1, \;i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1 \rangle$). But I am not sure if it still applies to 8 elements from the fundamental group of CW complex.

Comment: Well, if you can spot one element of order two, three of order four and they fulfill the relations that you mention then they form a group isomorphic with the quaternions.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I wasn't certain about the equivalences(like $i^2 = -1$ implies $|i|=4$), thank you for confirming!

Comment: The fact that $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$ uses all four generators, the last of which being the only one that is not over four and thus is two by supposition shows the development is $Q$.

Answer (score 2):

You have some group $G$ you want to see is isomorphic to $Q$. You have 4 elements $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ in $G$ that you think correspond to $i$, $j$, $k$, $-1$. So, form the candidate bijection
$f: \{i,j,k,-1\} \to \{a,b,c,d\}$. By hypothesis,
 $f(i)$, $f(j)$, $f(k)$, $f(-1)$ satisfy the relations in 
the presentation of $Q$, so we know $f$
can be extended to a homomorphism $\phi: Q \to G$. 
Every proper subgroup of $Q$ contains $-1$, but $\phi(-1) \neq 1$.
Therefore $\ker(\phi)=1$.  Since you already knew $a$, $b$,
$c$, $d$ generate $G$, you must have $\phi(Q) =G$. Therefore $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $G \cong Q$.

Comment: I don't see why you could conclude the injectivity of $\phi$ so easily. Is there a general criterion you are using here?

Comment: I've added an argument to the answer.